# R - Convert row-names to a vector

Tags: r, vector, rows

I just starting working with R and have a problem with my network-analysis.

I calculated the "outdegree" of a network. The output of the calculation is "values".

[image]

Now I tried to convert it to a dataframe with

```
data.outdegree <- as.data.frame(outdegree)
```

The problem is that the created dataframe has only one vector (Outdegree). The names of the companies are not a Vector, they are just a line caption.

[image]

Does someone know how to convert the line captions in an own vector for my dataframe?

Comment: Can you please show the console output of what `outdegree` and `outdegree.data` are instead of images? Thanks (you can edit the question to add it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
tibble::rownames_to_column(data.outdegree)
```